# How can I make an alphabet for a fictional dialect of a real language?

Tags: society, culture, language, space-colonization

The following post is copy-pasted from a similar question on Reddit:

Apparently, I already started work on the story and it turns out, that I have Ganymede speaking a fictional Russian dialect called Ganystravian Russian, or simply Ganystravian which is a mix of standard Russian, Ukrainian, Kazakh and Azerbaijani. However, I have no idea of how to make the alphabet of the fictional dialect, so how does one actually make a fictional dialect from a real life language?

And I am not sure if Artifexian can help (since...well, I have no idea whether he knows modern Russian enough to help). :/ NOTE: This is based on the same scenario I have been posting for the past two weeks, so try and look at my post history before you comment on this page. :/

Comment: Why wouldn't they use the Russian alphabet?  Possibly with some stealing from other languages.

Comment: @Brythan They would but....I want to actually mix bits and pieces of the other 3 into it. :/ That and pronunciation being altered, but not altered to the point of becoming a new language.

Comment: @Brythan So, any ideas?

Comment: You might look at the Turkish form of the Cyrillic alphabet. It's closer to the English alphabet.

Comment: This is a _really_ opinion-based question, which I don't think someone could answer meaningfully without knowing the specifics of the language itself.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about dialects and can't suggest much in those cases.  In regards to alphabets though, I think that there are some obvious steps that you haven't taken yet.  First, look up each language and find out what alphabet it uses.

- [Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet)
- [Ukrainian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_alphabet)
- [Kazakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakh_alphabets)
- [Azerbaijani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azerbaijani_alphabet)

I started with the four countries and followed links to the alphabet pages.

Note that all four use or have used [Cyrillic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script), which was the Soviet standard.  Kazakh and Azerbaijani also have used Arabic-based scripts.  Azerbaijani currently uses a latin-based script.

Second, look for places where they differ or have trouble representing something in Cyrillic.

Third, look for places where words make unique sense in one language.  A classic example is the word pork in English.  It derives from the word "porc" in French, which means pig.  After the Normans (Scandinavian in ancestry but French speaking after a long period in France) conquered England, they used their word when requesting pig meat.  So the French word became the word for pig meat while people continued to use the English word for pigs.

What words would be most natural in other languages?  Those are most likely to be represented in the original language and bring their letters.

Comment: @Brythan: Excellent answer. All I could add is that Azeri (not Azerbaijani) and Kazakh are Turkic languages, and as such need 2 vowels not present in Russian and Ukrainian. But if the majority of your speakers are Slavs, they would probably get around this by using approximations or digraphs. And just as a matter of interest - why would your alphabet be in alphabetical order, when there are much more rational orderings available?

Answer (score 2):

A little review of your alphabet ("А Б В Г Д Ӗ О̆ Ж З Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ И I Е Ў Ă") from a Russian POV.
Note: I assume, you intend your dialect to form naturally, not to be artificially created. Russian and Ukrainian already form natural mix-ups, [Surzhyk dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surzhyk). Kazahs and Azerbaijani, on the other hand, sound completely foreign to me, so adding these two to the mix would be difficult.

First, it's weird not to see the [soft sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_sign) (Ь). Russian heavily relies on "Ь", both phonetically and grammatically. For example, it defines a verb form: "учится" - "{he} studies", "учитЬся" - "to study". So, you need to think of a *very* good reasons for Russian-based language to omit "Ь". Ukrainian also uses "Ь", maybe to a lesser degree.
[Hard sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_sign) (Ъ), on another hand, is only used by Russian and its role is mostly phonetic and decorative. So it might be thrown away from the united alphabet.

Lack of Ю [yu] and Я [ya] is actually believable - they can be replaced by combinations "ЙУ" and "ЙА". The later one is already used in internet slang (in a kind of lolspeak).
Lack of "Ы" is plausible as long as you have "I" in alphabet. Sounds Ы and И in Russian are close to И and I in Ukrainian, so they might be replaced this way.
If you remove "Э", you need to introduce "Є". Sounds Э and E in Russian are close to E and Є in Ukrainian, so you need either Э or Є.

Ў, Ă, Ŏ and Ӗ are unlikely to appear (naturally, at least), since they aren't used in these 4 languages, and they usually represent "short sounds". Russian [determines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction_in_Russian) vowel length by its position relatively to the stressed vowel, so it doesn't need those letters.

You've got it right that there's no "Ё" in the common alphabet. This letter is often replaced by "Е" in chats and other informal media - mostly for speed and simplicity. 
I believe you won't get any diacritics in a common futuristic language - they take longer to write by hand and to recognize, since they don't have their own distinctive shape.

A minor detail: the order of letters looks odd. Historically, И, I and Е were commonly located in the middle of Cyrillic alphabets.

To sum up: "А Б В Г Д Е Є Ж З И I Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ь".
 
And I guess Ukrainian, Kazakh or Azerbaijani can find this alphabet missing something crucial to those languages.

Answer (score 1):

Pick the language whose native speakers form the highest proportion of the people whose input led to Ganystravian.

Write Ganystravian using, as best you can, the alphabet of that language.

Note that unless you are going to visually represent the written language, or a language barrier of some kind is an important plot element, you don't need an alphabet for Ganystravian.  Instead, use the alphabet of the language in which the story is written.